# Is my SSD about to break

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a laptop with an SSD and recently it has been giving me weird errors and I'm not sure whether it is software based or hardware based. Therefore I checked my SSD using the smartctl tool:

```
[root@laptop matthias]# smartctl -a /dev/sda
    smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.9.35-1-lts] (local build)
    Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     TOSHIBA THNSFJ256GDNU
Serial Number:    X57S10LDTBZW
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00080d 9104b419d
Firmware Version: JULA1102
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      < 1.8 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jul  5 18:45:20 2017 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0013   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7350
 10 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0013   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2795
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   187   187   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       91
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   055   032   000    Old_age   Always       -       45 (Min/Max 19/68)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0013   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 1
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1182 hours (49 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 88 18 dc b7 40  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00b7dc18 = 12049432

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 e8 88 18 dc b7 40 08      00:05:05.866  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 90 80 80 da b7 40 08      00:05:05.865  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 78 78 00 d8 b7 40 08      00:05:05.852  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 70 48 d3 b7 40 08      00:05:05.852  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 68 50 bb b7 40 08      00:05:05.836  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I have no Idea how to read this output. All I see is a lot of old age and pre fail. Is my SSD about to fail?

I also ran this:

```
[root@laptop matthias]# smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.9.35-1-lts] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7350
```

Comment: The old-age and pre-fail indicate the type of the value, not the current state. Look at when_failed for that. As for the error encountered, it's difficult to make predictions, but at the very least I'd suggest making sure you have a backup copy of your data just in case, and contacting the manufacturer for advice (perhaps a warranty replacement if it's new-ish).

Comment: So is my harddrive still alive and well?

Comment: It's not reporting SMART errors, but that does *not* mean it's fine. SMART can only tell you when something is failing; it cannot tell you for sure when something is *not* failing. It could spontaneously fail one day and SMART would never say a thing. Make sure you have backups, maybe try reconnecting it in case the cable works, and replace it if the errors are disruptive.